# How do I remove the white margin appearing on the right side of my website?

Tags: html, css

This is my first question.

I'm having some issue with a bug on my local webpage. I've been creating my own version of an Airbnb website, namely 'tombnb' for a few weeks now but have become stuck with a bug.

On the right side of my page, I have a white margin (about 20px wide) that I cannot rid of.

I hadn't had this problem before I recently added some code to my page to ensure that it's flow didn't change when I altered the size of the browser window. (I can't even remember what code that was) and despite removing that code, this white margin still remains.

Would somebody be able to give me some help in identifying what the cause of the problem is?

Thank you.

http://pastebin.com/J0aWAXcC - HTML

http://pastebin.com/tPdLXf20 - CSS

Comment: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: I just tried to work with your code, and I found out that you are missing on `</div>` so please figure that out. It will maybe fix it.

Comment: Not able to see any white space. Although there is horizontal and vertical scroll bar. Which white space you are talking about?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MadhawaMB/bu473xa3/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect, you are missing one `</div>`.

That will fix your problem.

Comment: Can you specify where the missing </div> is?

Comment: I can't see where it is missing.

Comment: I've removed <div id="main-container"> and <div id="inner-main-container"> from my code and this is has resolved the problem. My webpage is perfectly fine when the browser is maximized. Though when I reduce the browser windows size, I lose flow and the 'Venice' picture beneath the first three thumbnails creates some white space on the right side.